# Getting null values when using ajax serialize method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, jquery-callback

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#inputval").ready(function(){
var querystring = $(this).serialize();

alert(querystring);
$.ajax({
url: "/example",
type: "POST",
data: querystring,
})

});
});

</script>
```

` this is the script am using. someone kindly help me to find out what am doing wrong.

Comment: am trying to get the text values, which is inside the form. but am getting an empty values only

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/n04usjqo/1/
Open the console to see the query string

Comment: paulgv, thanks man. it works! how to up-vote your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

var querystring = $("#inputval").serialize();

console.log(querystring);
$.ajax({
url: "/example",
type: "POST",
data: querystring,
})

});

</script>

Credits & thanks to- http://stackoverflow.com/users/4114297/paulgv
```